# Python Bluetooth LE subscription on Windows 10

Tags: python, c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I fear this is going to be a no, but is there a way to have python 3 on windows 10, discover, connect and get subscription updates from a bluetooth Low Energy device? Bleak and other similar libraries do not seem to work.

If that is not a solution, is it possible that something like C++ would work? My end goal is to have something connect to a bluetooth device, the script/program to read what the device is sending it, then translate that into keyboard inputs.

I am willing to pick up another language to make this happen, just not really sure where to start.